# How can I add a getter to a Dart class with a named parameter on its constructor?

Tags: dart, getter, named-parameters

Suppose I have the following Dart class, with a named parameter in its constructor:

```
class TestClass {
  final int someValue;
  TestClass({this.someValue});
}

void someMethod() {
  TestClass testClass = new TestClass(someValue: 10);
  print(testClass.someValue);
}
```

How can I add a getter for the field? I was trying something along the lines of:

```
class TestClass {
  final int _someValue;
  TestClass({this.someValue});
  int get someValue => _someValue+2;
}
```

Comment: Technically, you already have a getter for the field. I'm guessing you want to keep the field non-final and only expose a getter for it (which is where you usually do the private-field/public-getter pattern), and also want a named constructor parameter to initialize the field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Named parameters can't be private, but you can get the results you want using a named parameter, a private member, and an initializer.  You could do the same thing in the constructor body without the initializer, but then `_someValue` couldn't be final.

```
class TestClass {
  final int _someValue;

  TestClass({int someValue}) : _someValue = someValue;

  int get someValue => _someValue;
}
```

However, there is very little value to doing this in Dart.  A getter without a corresponding setter is semantically equivalent to a final field.

Answer (score 0):

`TestClass({this.someValue});`

There's no member variable by that name.  Did you mean `_someValue`?

Comment: I don't mean anything. The "I was trying something along the lines of" is just random code that doesn't work. TestClass({this._someValue}) also doesn't work.